# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

I'm doing a registration form which contains username,password,email and country.
whenever I submit the data , following  error is showing up :
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver

Following is my code:

register.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.sql.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

 @WebServlet("/servregister")
    public class Register extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
    response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    doPost(request,response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");

    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

    String n = request.getParameter("username");
    String u = request.getParameter("password");
    String em = request.getParameter("usermail");
    String c = request.getParameter("usercountry");

    try{
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/e48265/Documents/Database2.accdb");
        System.out.println("connection made...");

        PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into Register values(?,?,?,?)");

        ps.setString(1, n);
        ps.setString(2, u);
        ps.setString(3, em);
        ps.setString(4, c);

        int i=ps.executeUpdate();
        if(i>0){
            out.print("user successfully registered");
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException ce){
            ce.printStackTrace();
        }


    out.close();

}

}
```

I've added all 5 jar files of ucanaccess in eclipse and  in web appication's WebContent - WEB-INF - lib folder. Can anyone solve this?

Comment: Ucanaccess version is 4.0.2

Comment: when the application is started are the jars in WEB-INF/lib? (asking because we don't usually "add" jar in here, we deploy some war with jars inside)

Comment: Yes I added jars in WEB-INF/lib folder